# Python: converting txt to gpickle and looking for nodes and edges in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm trying to convert .txt to .gpickle in order to **obtain the nodes and edges in networkx**. I used the following codes to do so:

```
M = open("data.txt", "r")
G=nx.path_graph(M)
>>> nx.write_gpickle(G,"data.gpickle")
>>> G=nx.read_gpickle("data.gpickle")
```

After looking up the nodes and edges:

```
G.nodes()
G.edges()
```

I got outputs such as `NodeView(())` and `EdgeView([])`, which should contain numerical values in the brackets. I assume that `G=nx.path_graph(M)` is the problem since it worked fine when I tried using the example from the reference:

```
>>> G = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> nx.write_gpickle(G, "test.gpickle")
>>> G = nx.read_gpickle("test.gpickle")
```

Comment: what is in your `data.txt` file?

Comment: the file contains only numerical values generally organized in a 2x100 format, but the values in the second row cuts off towards the middle. I'm guessing that my txt file was just not organized in the correct way, thus the command won't work.

Comment: can you include this file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ou4n38yek1u5poc/data.txt?dl=0                              Sorry my mistake on the txt file. It looked like 2 by 100 when I open on notepad, but it is actually 16 by 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a weighted adjacency matrix in `data.txt`, the example you are using is to create a path graph, which has nothing to do with the information in your data. In order to create the proper graph, `networkx` cannot read it directly with that format. However, you can use `numpy` or `pandas` to read `data.txt` and then convert it to a `networkx` graph.
See the following code to get your graph with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

numpy_array = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter='\t', dtype='float')
G = nx.from_numpy_array(numpy_array)
```

Now you will have

```
In [1]: G.nodes()
Out[1]: NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15))
In [2]: G.edges()
Out[2]: EdgeView([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 12), (0, 13), (0, 14), (0, 15), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 15), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (2, 13), (2, 14), (2, 15), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 13), (3, 14), (3, 15), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (4, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (5, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 11), (6, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14), (6, 15), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (7, 13), (7, 14), (7, 15), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (8, 13), (8, 14), (8, 15), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (9, 13), (9, 14), (9, 15), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 15), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (11, 15), (12, 13), (12, 14), (12, 15), (13, 14), (13, 15), (14, 15)])
```

To save your graph with `gpickle` format you do:

```
nx.write_gpickle(G, 'my_graph.gpickle')
```

Now you should be able to read it with `G = nx.read_gpickle('my_graph.gpickle')`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It works great now. I didn't realized that 'numpy' was needed for my work.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your data, you may read them directly, using networkx `read_edgelist` function, then write it into a pickle using its [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('test.txt', delimiter='\t', data=[('weight', int)], create_using=nx.DiGraph())

nx.write_gpickle(G, "test.gpickle")
```